# How can multiple requests used to populate models be handled using RXJava Observables?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, observable, rx-android

We are using ReactiveX and Retrofit in our network stack to handle all API requests in an asynchronous way.

Our goal is to create one method that will return a completely populated collection of `User` models. Each `User` model has a list of `Pet` objects. We can fetch all of the `User` models with one request. However, `Pet` models need to be requested per `User`.

Getting users is simple:

```
// Service.java
@GET("users/?locationId={id}")
Observable<List<User>> getUsersForLocation(@Path("id") int locationId);

@GET("pets/?userId={id}")
Observable<List<Pet>> getPetsForUser(@Path("id") int userId);

// DataManager.java
public Observable<List<User>> getUsersForLocation(int locationId) {
    return api.getUsersForLocation(locationId);
}

public Observable<List<Pet>> getPetsForUser(int userId) {
    return api.getPetsForUser(userId);
}
```

We would like to find some convenient (RX style) way of looping through the `User` list, fetching the `Pet`s for that each user, assigning them to the `User` and ultimately returning the `Observable<List<User>>`.

I am fairly new to RX. I've looked over the documentation and have tried using various methods such as `flatMap()` and `zip`, however, I have yet to find the exact combination of transforms or combiners to make it happen.

Comment: In this presentation Jake Wharton does exactly this: https://goo.gl/01Evkm

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm currently using Java 7 and the use of lambdas in that presentation obscure what is happening in those method calls to flatMap(). Any insights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a small sample app that makes what you are trying to achieve. Here the components:

```
public class Datasource {

    public Observable<List<User>> users() {
        return Observable.just(Arrays.asList(
                new User("1", "Foo"), new User("2", "Bar")
        ));
    }

    public Observable<List<Pet>> pets(User user) {
        return Observable.just(Arrays.asList(
                new Pet(user.getName() + "'s cat"),
                new Pet(user.getName() + "'s dog")
        ));
    }
}
```

Pet class:

```
public class Pet {
    private String mName;

    public Pet(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pet{" +
                "mName='" + mName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {

    private String mName;
    private String mId;
    private List<Pet> mPetList;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this(id, name, Collections.<Pet>emptyList());
    }

    public User(String id, String name, List<Pet> pets) {
        mName = name;
        mId = id;
        mPetList = pets;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public User copyWithPets(List<Pet> pets) {
        return new User(mId, mName, pets);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "mName='" + mName + '\'' +
                ", mId='" + mId + '\'' +
                ", mPetList=" + mPetList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Put all together:

```
datasource.users()
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<User>, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<User> call(List<User> users) {
                return Observable.from(users);
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<User> call(final User user) {
                return datasource.pets(user)
                        .map(new Func1<List<Pet>, User>() {
                            @Override
                            public User call(List<Pet> pets) {
                                return user.copyWithPets(pets);
                            }
                        });
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<User> users) {
                for (User user : users) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "user: " + user.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

It produces:

```
D/MainActivity: user: User{mName='Foo', mId='1', mPetList=[Pet{mName='Foo's cat'}, Pet{mName='Foo's dog'}]}
D/MainActivity: user: User{mName='Bar', mId='2', mPetList=[Pet{mName='Bar's cat'}, Pet{mName='Bar's dog'}]}
```

If it doesn't answer you question please post you actual datamodel for User and Pet.

Comment: Awesome, such wow! Your post helped me too! Thank you Sir! :)