# RxAndroid response of one call to make another request

Tags: operators, retrofit, rx-java, chaining, rx-android

I'm new to RxAndroid and trying to chain responses.

I'm using this [github](https://api.github.com/repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues) API to retrieve data. Along with each issue there are comments link and events link associated with it which I want to fetch and update existing object with list of comments and events to form something like this.

```
[

issue: {

 comments: [

    {
     .
     .
    },
    {
     .
     .
    }
 ]

events : [

    {
     .
     .
    },
    {
     .
     .
    }
 ]

]

]
```

I could retrieve initial response with following code

```
GitHubService gitHubService = ServiceFactory.createServiceFrom(GitHubService.class, GitHubService.ENDPOINT);

    gitHubService.getIssuesList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(issues -> Arrays.asList(issues))
            .subscribe(adapter::add);
```

Now How do I retrieve comments and events before updating adapter ? I want to show 3 comments and 3 events as well.

Comment: Check if this is helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34433400/321354

Comment: You might want to use Schedulers.io() instead of Schedulers.newThread() as it  creates a new Thread for each unit of work In general if you want to chain multiple web services you could use flatmap for it Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to  @Riccardo Ciovati for your example !

Here is my solution. and it works perfectly !

```
public static void getIssuesForRepo(final IssuesListAdapter adapter) {

    GitHubService gitHubService = ServiceFactory.createServiceFrom(GitHubService.class, GitHubService.ENDPOINT);

    gitHubService.getIssuesList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(issues -> Arrays.asList(issues))
            .flatMap(issues -> Observable.from(issues))
            .filter(issue -> issue.getCommentsUrl() != null)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Issue, Observable<Issue>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Issue> call(Issue issue) {


                    return gitHubService.getComments(issue.getNumber())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .map(comments -> {

                                issue.setCommentList(Arrays.asList(comments));

                                return issue;
                            });
                }


            })
            .toList()
            .subscribe(adapter::add);

}
```

where

```
public interface GitHubService {

  String ENDPOINT = "https://api.github.com/";

  @GET("repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues")
  Observable<Issue[]> getIssuesList();

  @GET("repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues/{number}/comments")
  Observable<Comment[]> getComments(@Path("number") long number);

 }
```