# RxAndroid - execute another request based on a specific result?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, restful-architecture, rx-android

i am using RxAndroid/RxJava for the first time and trying to figure out how to implement a chain of requests but each next request made is dependent on the result of the other.

example:

```
private Boolean isUserEligible(){
        ..
    }

    private String registerDevice()
        ..
    }

    private String login(){
        ..
    }
```

As far as i know, the Observable can only execute all of the above methods or one by one like below:

```
 // Fetch from both simultaneously
    Observable<String> zipped
            = Observable.zip(isUserEligible(), registerDevice(),login(), new Func2<String, String, String>() {

    });

    Observable<String> concatenated = Observable.concat(isUserEligible(), registerDevice(),login());
```

what if i want to do something like this

```
//execute usUserEligible first and if eligible, execute registerDevice, else execute login().
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713433/rxandroid-response-of-one-call-to-make-another-request

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of these methods return observables, you could write:

```
Observable<String> response = isUserEligible()
        .flatMap(isEligible -> isEligible ? registerDevice() : login());
```

Without retro-lambda; you could write:

```
Observable<String> response = isUserEligible()
        .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<String>>() {
            public Observable<String> call(final Boolean isEligible) {
                return isEligible ? registerDevice() : login();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Android doesnt support Lambdan expressions

Comment: I would recommend using retro-lambda if you can! Otherwise its not too hard to create an anon class to replace this lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for a flatmap.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Create the mapping from the first result to a second observable, here you can use the result of the first function to input it into the second.

```
final Func1<Boolean, Observable<String>> registerFunc = isEligible -> {
    return registerDevice(isEligible)
};
```

Now you have to create your chain of calls and flatMaps: do the first call, and flatmap the resulting Observable with the function you just created. This will again return an Observable. you can keep chaining it here with other flatmaps

```
isUserEligible().flatMap(registerFunc);
```

Be aware that all your functions need to return Observables to make this possible.